# In ruby, how can I capture stdout using a puts and an instance variable. I need to use the instance variable to pass an rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, stdout

Extracting the relevant code snippets from my project to a small standalone test module for clarity ...

```
require "stringio"  

@output = $stdout
$buffer = StringIO.new
$stdout = $buffer

@output.puts "puts method to buffer text" 
$stdout = STDOUT 

$buffer.rewind 
puts "buffer contents: #{$buffer.read}"
```

Running this code, returns an empty buffer. I have to use the @output.puts to pass an rspec @output(:puts) should_receive rspec test. If I replace the @output.puts with a simple "puts", the buffer is populated but the rspec test fails.

I have searched various online ruby resources for a couple of hours now and cannot use any of the content to answer this question. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: So the `@output.puts` should write to both standard out and the buffer at the same time?

Comment: I'm with Daniël in questioning what you expect.  `$buffer` should be empty based on the code you have here, and it's not clear why you're surprised by that or what you want.  The string `"puts method to buffer text"` is being written to `STDOUT` while your empty StringIO is never written to.  Are you expecting something else to happen?

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Darshan. No, I'm not exptecting the buffer to be populated from code above but am trying to figure out how to make it so! I know that I'm not actually writing anything to $buffer and this is why it's empty. What I was trying to avoid was writing the output twice. i.e. once @output.puts to pass the rspec test and again to $buffer to populate the buffer. I want them both to capture the contents of STDOUT without fudging the code.

Comment: AND I'm not allowed change the rspec test (project), it still has to pass @output.should_receive(:puts) rpsec test.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Simple error in the end.

Firstly, inserting a

```
$buffer.write
```

line means I am actually writing to the buffer so it's not empty!

Secondly,

```
@output.puts("string")
```

doesn't actually assign the string contents to @output ,just uses it as an output channel so

```
$buffer.write(@output)
```

just writes hex characters not my string to the buffer.

So I have to explicitly write the string or assign it to the variable i.e.

```
@output="string"
$buffer.write(@output)
```

to write the string to the buffer.

Thanks for all the responses which set me researching/thinking in the right way - onwards and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'stringio'

def read_stdout(&block)
  tmp = $stdout
  $stdout = tmp = StringIO.new
  block.call
  tmp.string
  ensure
   $stdout = tmp # ensures that always evaluated
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could redesign your code to not rely on puts and allow injection of the output stream it writes to with STDOUT being the default so your app code doesn't have to change.

```
class Foo
  def something_cool
    puts "this is an artifact I want to test"
  end
end
```

Becomes...

```
class Foo
  def initialize(out=STDOUT)
    @out = out
  end

  def something_cool
    output "this is an artifact I want to test"
  end

  private
  def output(msg)
    @out.write("#{msg}\n")
  end
end
```

And your test becomes...

```
out = StringIO.new
Foo.new(out)
Foo.something_cool
out.rewind.read.should eq("this is an artifact I want to test\n")
```

Comment: Thanks Lance. I'll have a play with output and write methods as I've not used yet. The problem is, I'm not allowed change the rspec test (project). It has to pass as @output.should_receive(:puts).